# SVGs don't show on Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, svg, graphics

I am using a bunch of SVGs on my site. They show just find on Chrome but on Firefox they don't show at all.

I've been trying to find info on that but surprisingly there isn't that much. Everything I found talks about defining the sizes of the SVG, and I've tried doing thatand defining the size everywhere but it doesn't work, or I am just doing it wrong.

This is the sprite I am using:

```
<symbol id="heart"  width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>heart</title>
<path d="M12 4.435c-1.989-5.399-12-4.597-12 3.568 0 4.068 3.06 9.481 12 14.997 8.94-5.516 12-10.929 12-14.997 0-8.118-10-8.999-12-3.568z"/>
</symbol>
```

This is how I place it in my component:

```
<svg className="room__favorite-heart room__favorite-heart--empty">
    <use xlinkHref="../sprite.svg#heart"></use>
</svg>
```

This is my css:

```
.room {
  &__favorite-heart {
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    &--full {
      fill: $mainColor;
    }
    &--empty {
      fill: $greyLightest;
    }
  }
}
```

and also

```
.icon-testing{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: That’s not valid CSS. Is it getting compiled by something?

Comment: I'm using SVGs in one of my React apps and they show just fine on Chrome and Firefox, so it must be something else in your code

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's scss

Comment: @HermitCrab I've placed all the relevant code here, not sure what else it could be

Comment: Firefox does not support rem units with SVG.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012081/firefox-esr-68-doesnt-support-rem-units-in-an-svgs-dimensions-workarounds

Answer (score 0):

I do not code in your environment so I focus only on SVG here some things I spot:

1. **Your path should be inside `<g> <\g>` tag**

   I know its optional but may be its just that the Firefox decoder its expecting it (just guessing).  So just try...
2. **I see no `stroke/fill` settings in your SVG**

   this is most likely the problem. Here SVG with such settings:

   ```
   <svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="3.621934 13.621934 90.255485 62.818094" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="1px" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0" >
    <g stroke="blue">
     <path id=" " stroke="magenta" d="M 10 70 a 133.591805 50 12.97728 0 0 70 -50 "/>
     <path id=" " stroke="red"     d="M10.000000 70.000000 C24.500960 70.325512 38.696601 69.272793 49.846109 67.045096 C60.995616 64.817400 70.632828 61.108261 76.897046 56.633820 C83.161264 52.159379 86.914255 46.304086 87.431414 40.198450 C87.948573 34.092813 85.301045 26.896880 80.000000 20.000000 "/>
    </g>
   </svg>
   ```